# Page loaded signal

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

We have a gui with multiple pages. On each page there are custom text components with a data coupling. When a page is shown/loaded the text components update their data binding using the `Component.oncompleted` and `onVisibleChanged` signals. To finalize this a call must be made to the communication module after each child has done its updates.

When pages are changed this can be done in the "onVisibleChanged" of the page. The problem is finding a point to do this when the page is created. The `Component.onCompleted` is performed before the one of the children.

Do you know any signal to use for this?

As a workaround I have an empty `NumberAnimation` with a `Component.onCompleted` call. This apperently runs after the children but feels like a hack.

Here goes the example code

DataText

```
DataText
{
    property string address: ""
    text: name + Model.getSingleItems().get(address).value //property binding here
    onVisibleChanged: { Model.getSingleItems().setSubscribeStatus(address, visible);} //Stages the address for (un)subscribe
    Component.onCompleted:{ Model.getSingleItems().setSubscribeStatus(address, visible);} //Stages the address for (un)subscribe
}
```

An example page

```
Rectangle
{
    DataText
    {
        address: "datakey"
    }

    //This code must be executed after all setSubscribeStatus calls to 
    //finish the subscriptions.
    Component.onCompleted:{ Model.getSingleItems().finialize();} 
    onVisibleChanged: { Model.getSingleItems().finialize();}
}
```

I'm looking for a way to subscribe to a batch of data adresses in the communication module. We can't keep all the data up to date due to limitations in our bandwith with the actual device.

Comment: Why can't you use property bindings instead of reacting to signals everywhere? A code sample will get you a better answer.

Comment: As you experienced `Component.onCompleted` does not enforce any ordering and thus cannot be used in a reliable way. You can define custom signals and handle them in `on<signal_name>` handlers for specific purposes. Anyhow, property bindings can cover most of the cases and should be preferred, at least for what you've told us. As @Mitch said, please show some code.